# $f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+nx}$ in $C[0,1]$ with usual sup-norm metric.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I need to check whether it is Cauchy or not:

> > $f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+nx}$ in $C[0,1]$ with usual sup-norm metric.

As,I know the sequence is Cauchy if for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a no $N$ such that $d(f_m,f_n)<\epsilon$ for all $m,n>N$. So I was calculating $d(f_m,f_n)$ which I got is this:
$$d(f_m,f_n)=(m-n)\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\frac{x}{(mx+1)(nx+1)}$$
Now I am not understanding how to deal with this.

Comment: $d(f_m,f_n)$ is a little inconvenient to deal with. What is the pointwise limit of $(f_n)$?

Comment: Though it's not difficult to see that $f(f_{2n}, f_n) \geqslant \frac{1}{6}$ for $n > 0$.

Comment: No, that's not the pointwise limit.

Comment: Almost. There's one point that begs to differ.

Comment: if $x$ not $0$, then....

Comment: C[0,1] complete. So convergent cauchy is same. Limit function is not continuous.Limit is outside of C[0,1]?....

Comment: Yep. The limit of a uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions is continuous. The pointwise limit of this sequence isn't continuous, hence the sequence doesn't converge uniformly. Hence it's not a Cauchy sequence in $C([0,1])$.

Comment: Can u link a proof of "limit of a uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions is continuous"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m=n^2$, then, as $n$ goes to infinity, we have that
$$d(f_{n^2},f_n)=(n^2-n)\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\frac{x}{(n^2x+1)(nx+1)}\\
\stackrel{x=1/n}{\geq} (n^2-n)\frac{(1/n)}{(n^2(1/n)+1)(n(1/n)+1)}
=\frac{n-1}{2(n+1)}\to \frac{1}{2}\not=0.$$
Hence $(f_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is not a Cauchy sequence (and the sequence is not (uniformly) convergent in $C[0,1]$).

P.S. Note that the pointwise limit is the function which is $1$ in $(0,1]$ and it is 0 at 0. It is not continuous in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Pedrick Serre Is my answer convincing?

Comment: I dont understand how supremum is greater than the case x=1/n?

Comment: @Pedrick Serre The supremum is taken in $[0,1]$ and $1/n\in[0,1]$.