# problem on cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Which of the following sequence $\{f_n\}$ are Cauchy Sequences?

$1$.$f_n(x)=\frac{x+n}{n}$ in $C[0,1]$ with usual sup-norm metric

$2$.$f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+nx}$ in $C[0,1]$ with usual sup-norm metric

My attempts  : i thinks   None  of these  are  cauchy  sequence

because  for  for option   $1$)  $f_n(x)=\frac{x+n}{n}=  \frac{x}{n} + 1  \neq 0 $ so  it  is  not cauchy

For option $2)$$f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+nx} \le  1 \neq 0$ so it is not cauchy

is  its  True ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that each $f_n$ is a single point in the vector space $C[0, 1]$. You appear to be testing whether each point in the sequence is the point $0$. This will certainly guarantee that the sequence is Cauchy if true! But, not every Cauchy sequence is the constant $0$ sequence.

To prove Cauchiness, there's a couple of ways. You can either do it by definition directly, or you can show that $f_n$ converges. Every convergent sequence is automatically Cauchy (and indeed, since $C[0, 1]$ is complete, Cauchiness and convergence are equivalent). The limit of a Cauchy sequence in $C[0, 1]$ turns out to be the pointwise limit. For the first case, if $f$ is the pointwise limit, then

$$f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{n} + 1 = 1.$$

That is, the only possibly limit for $f_n$ is the constant function $1$. To prove convergence, you need to show that, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that

$$n > N \implies \|f_n - f\| < \varepsilon$$

We have that

\begin{align*}
\|f_n - f\| &= \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} f_n(x) - f(x) \\
&= \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} \frac{x}{n} + 1 - 1 \\
&= \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} \frac{x}{n}.
\end{align*}

Note that, regardless of $n$, the function $\frac{x}{n}$ is always increasing, and achieves its maximum at $x = 1$. That is,

$$\|f_n - f\| = \frac{1}{n}$$

So, given a fixed $\varepsilon > 0$, we must choose an $N$ such that

$$n > N \implies \frac{1}{n} < \varepsilon,$$

so we can just choose $N = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$.

As for the other question, you can find an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035794/f-nx-fracnx1nx-in-c0-1-with-usual-sup-norm-metric?rq=1).

Comment: thanks  u  @ TheoBendit